# Jquery script not working in script but working in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar

I have a navbar and is applying a script to it so that when it scrolls the background color changes. I attached this script at the end of the HTML script, after `<body>`

It doesn't work but if I manually put it through console it works perfectly...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      $(".navbar").css("background-color", "#222");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar" style="height:200px">Navbar</div>
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console when it does not work?

Comment: did you try the window.$(window).load(function () {/*your code*/});

Comment: It works in the snippet I made you.

Comment: @glovemobile `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen oh i actually get an error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $" but the exact same code manually put in console finds the variable no problem

Comment: It's likely that your code is in the html *before* the jquery.js `<script>` tag - make sure jquery script tag is before your code.

Comment: @freedomn-m omg smart man geniius